# need to link image to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I need to link an image to the post it matches. Any help on how to accomplish this would be great!

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td width="13%" height="120px"> 
      <% if post.images.empty? %>
        <% image_tag "{https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Duck%20Duck%20Jeep/Dollarphotoclub_70624208.jpg?_subject_uid=202757157&w=AACUcUehkUyn1S_gIrkrAtC0GKoAac2XAjCjZXHuwgapQA}", class: "thumbnail", class: "img-responsive" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag post.images.first.url, class: "thumbnail", class: "img-responsive"  %>
      <% end %>
    </td>

    <td><%= link_to post.heading, post %></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= link_to (image_tag(...)), target_url %>` should work. Specify the `image_tag params` & `target_url` appropriately.

In your code, the `<% image_tag "{https://dl-web...` should actually be `<%= image_tag "{https://dl-web...` for the image to show up. `<% .. %>` only evaluates the expression within, whereas `<%= .. %>` evaluates the expression and includes its output.

Comment: That is  killing 2 birds with one stone!

Comment: could you change my question post to reflect the code...I am having trouble. I want the image to link to my posts show page

Comment: Not sure what the code the question is trying to do; here is an example from one of my projects : `<%= link_to image_tag(image_file_for(user)), user_path(user)  %>`; the `image_file_for` helper method takes a `user` and returns the file path for the image associated with the user.